# How to set Adapter to show ListFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How to set `Adapter` to show `ListFragment` ,and I try to set code this bottom
is not work

`ListFragment` is show only one value (index=0) and other index is not show

ChatGroupMembersFragment.java

```
public class ChatGroupMembersFragment extends ListFragment {


    ArrayList<ChatApiFriendListGroupModel> chatApiFriendListGroupModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ChatApiFriendListGroupModel> chatApiFriendListGroupModels = new ArrayList<>();
    private AdapChatGroupMembers adapChatGroupMembers;
    public static ArrayList<ChatApiFriendListGroupModel> f =new ArrayList<>();

    public static ChatGroupMembersFragment newInstance(ChatApiFriendListGroupModel member) {


        f.add(member);



        return new ChatGroupMembersFragment();
    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("ChatGroupMembersFragmen","onViewCreated");
        ShareData.tx_home_titlebar.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.tx_group_member));


        Member();
    }

    private void Member() {



        for (ChatApiFriendListGroupModel chatApiFriend: f){


            chatApiFriendListGroupModelArrayList.add(chatApiFriend);

        }



        adapChatGroupMembers = new AdapChatGroupMembers(getActivity(), chatApiFriendListGroupModelArrayList);
        setListAdapter(adapChatGroupMembers);
        adapChatGroupMembers.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

and myadapter

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHoder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView==null){
            convertView =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_group_members,parent ,false);
            viewHoder.tx_name_member = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tx_name_member);
            viewHoder.img_profile_member =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_profile_member);

            viewHoder.tx_name_member.setTypeface(MainActivity.typeface_normal);
            convertView.setTag(viewHoder);
        }else {
            viewHoder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHoder.tx_name_member.setText(chatApiFriendListGroupModelArrayList.get(position).getMembers().get(position).getFirstname());

        return convertView;
    }
```

and it show only one in listview (`get(0).getFirstName();`)

and My Data have 6 value in FirstName (`get(0-6).getFirstName()`)

How to get all value to show `ListFragment` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your `ArrayList` has only one element, which you add here:

```
f.add(member);
```

So the following call will only return an element when the position is `0`:

```
chatApiFriendListGroupModelArrayList.get(position);
```

If i understand correctly and `getMembers()` return your proper dataset, you might want to do something like this:

```
viewHoder.tx_name_member.setText(chatApiFriendListGroupModelArrayList.get(0)
   .getMembers().get(position).getFirstname());
```

And override `getCount()` accordingly:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return chatApiFriendListGroupModelArrayList.get(0)
        .getMembers().size();
}
```